# Inner Join returning nothing

Tags: database, foreach, inner-join

MY Database:

```
CREATE TABLE EXPERIENCIA(
     exp_pri INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     nome VARCHAR(150),
     email VARCHAR(50),       
     exp VARCHAR(100),  
     PRIMARY KEY(exp_pri)
);

CREATE TABLE PRANCHA(
    prancha_pri INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,    
    tamanho_prancha VARCHAR(8),
    meio_prancha VARCHAR(2),
    litragem_prancha VARCHAR(3),
    PRIMARY KEY (prancha_pri)
);

CREATE TABLE ALTURAPESOESTILO(
    idAltPes INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    idExp INT,
    idPrancha INT,
    altura VARCHAR(4),
    peso VARCHAR(3),
    estilo VARCHAR(15),
    primary key (idAltPes),
    constraint fk_idExp foreign key (idExp) references EXPERIENCIA (exp_pri),
    constraint fk_idPrancha foreign key (idPrancha) references PRANCHA (prancha_pri)
 );
```

My SQL:

```
$query = "SELECT EXP.exp, 
          AEP.altura, 
          AEP.peso, 
          AEP.estilo, 
          PRAN.tamanho_prancha, 
          PRAN.meio_prancha, 
          PRAN.litragem_prancha 
   FROM EXPERIENCIA AS EXP 
   INNER JOIN ALTURAPESOESTILO AS AEP 
   ON (EXP.exp_pri = AEP.idAltPes) 
   INNER JOIN PRANCHA AS PRAN 
   ON (PRAN.prancha_pri = AEP.idAltPes)";

 $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao,$query);

 $retorno = array();

 while($experiencia = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
    $retorno[] = $experiencia;
 }

 return $retorno;
```

}

INDEX.PHP

```
 include 'banco.php';

    $resultado = array();
    $resultado = BuscaAlgo($conexao);


    foreach($resultado as $valor)
    {
        echo $valor['exp']; print(' '); echo $valor['altura']; print(' '); echo $valor['peso'];  
        echo $valor['estilo']; print(' '); echo $valor['tamanho_prancha']; print(' '); echo $valor['meio_prancha'];
        print(' '); echo $valor['litragem_prancha'];  ?><br> <?php  
    }
```

I'm joining three tables and trying to display them. But both put directly in MySql as in my code, nothing is returned. It does not error, but nothing is displayed.

What can it be?

Comment: Please give input, output and expected output for when you ran your query. Read about  [mcve]s. PS You have asked for only rows of the cross product of the three tables where EXP.exp_pri = PRAN.prancha_pri = AEP.idAltPes. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have asked for only the rows of the cross product of the three tables where

```
EXP.exp_pri = PRAN.prancha_pri = AEP.idAltPes
```

Is that what you really want? You haven't told us what your tables mean. But it seems extremely unlikely that your `AEP` `idAltPes` values are supposed to be equal to those in the other columns. If they aren't equal to any then you get no rows back. Considering your foreign key declarations, likely instead you want:

```
AEP.idExp = EXP.exp_pri AND AEP.idPrancha = PRAN.exp_pri
```

So

```
FROM ALTURAPESOESTILO AEP
INNER JOIN EXPERIENCIA EXP 
ON (EXP.exp_pri = AEP.idExp) 
INNER JOIN PRANCHA PRAN 
ON (PRAN.prancha_pri = AEP.idPrancha)
```

Answer (score 1):

INNER JOINs are exclusive and will require matching non-null values in both tables. I noticed that you have defined Foreign key relationships in the third table with the first two tables.

Is there a reason for not using the foreign key constraint columns in the INNER JOIN ? The constraint will ensure matching non null values in both primary and dependent tables.